# Mobile phone apps that would allow for students to anonymously "buzz" me in real time?

Tags: technology-in-education

Are there any mobile phone apps that would allow for students to anonymously "buzz" me in real time? What I have visualized is a free app students can download that features a button they can press that will signal me by making a light blink on a website. A noise might be distracting.

This would be especially suitable during the days where I teach more difficult topics. On certain days I anticipate more, maybe smaller confusions. Only some students feel comfortable asking questions, and those that do often will limit themselves to one or two.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're thinking by "anonymously"? Do you mean that no one except the student, including you, will know who is buzzing? Or do you mean that no other students will know, but it's okay if you know who is buzzing?

Comment: @shoover either is fine I suppose

Comment: This question may be too broad for this site. How exactly is this focused on *math education*?

Comment: @BrendanW.Sullivan in a pedagogical sense? I suppose not much, but I would be used in a statistics course

Comment: Is the idea that once the light blinks, you would know that you should stop and ask for questions?

Comment: @ChrisCunningham yes, usually I try to read facial expressions, but that isn’t always there (e.g. students get tired and tune out)

Comment: Ever heard of Slack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might just want to use a game buzzer app. There are tons of them for jeopardy like games/pub quizes that you can find online. Students have to sign up but they don’t have to use their real names. Looking around a bit I found the following free version

https://buzzin.live/play

which you can use in a browser. It’s very simple but I played around with a bit and it does everything you need it to do. There’s probably something more robust out there but I haven’t used any other myself and so don’t want to recommend.

I’ve thought about using such a system for students to tell me to speed up or slow down, but for the life of me I cant find a free multiple choice version.